# JFrame in Netbeans not showing the form but in the output it shows build success

Tags: java, forms, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm using Mac, Netbeans 12.0

I made a form and when I run the project it doesn’t show me the form but in the output, it shows build success.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dzzu.png]

Comment: 1) Don't post an image of your code. 2) if you have a runtime error then post the stack trace as text with your question.

Comment: Sidebar: *"but in the output it shows build success"* There is lots of code that will show no errors at compile or build-time, but instead at run-time.

Comment: As for the *'your code'*, for better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. (As text, like @camickr advised above.)